# open file in an hidden buffer

Tags: buffers

I want to open a file invisibly such that I can operate using normal (programmatic) commands on it.
How can it be achieved?
Preferably, it should be hidden from the beginning.

Thanks

Comment: You can load a file into a hidden buffer, but you cannot apply Normal or Ex commands to it (until it's finally shown in any window). So your question as it stands is invalid.

Comment: For any interaction with a buffer, it needs to be loaded and displayed in a window. So please mention what your actual goal is that you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 2):

If you are in a running vim instance and you need to add a new file you can use the `argadd` command (documented at [`:h :argadd`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/editing.txt.html#%3Aargadd)).

For example if I start vim with `vim foo` and use `:argadd bar`. I can then use `argdo [mycommand` to apply a command on all the files in the argument list.

For more details on the argument list see [`:h arglist`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/editing.txt.html#arglist).